# Searching files for specific words or phrases

Tags: linux, grep

I have word like initialize_my_var:   in sample.php

and I included three library files, take it as a.php, b.php, c.php ,

I really don't know where my label(initialize_my_var: ) definition is present in my library

files, is it possible with a pattern matching string to find which library file really have the exact term "initialize_my_var:" , I'm really looking for an exact pattern match.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
grep initialize_my_var a.php b.php c.php
```

It will show you which file(s) and what the line number(s) are.

Comment: `fgrep` or `grep -f` is a little faster in general since there is no regexp matching.  For three, likely small files, grep or fgrep won't matter too much,  but if these three also include other files that may want to be searched (like an additional hundred), then fgrep might have an advantage.

Comment: @Arcege: True. For GNU and BSD `grep`, it's `grep -F` (lowercase `-f` specifies a file to read patterns from).